# Rails - permissions to view specific attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

I want to be able to share a link to a `Property` model whilst setting permissions on which attributes the recipient can see. I've been through a few different ideas but none of them have felt 100% right. The closest I think I've come is this:

Have a `Share` model that belongs to `Property`. It also has an attribute called `permissions` which is a string.

On the create `Share` page I generate a series of checkboxes using `Property.column_names`. The benefit of this part is that I can add more attributes to Property without needing to change any code. Before the `Share` is created it converts the permissions params into a string.

When the user visits the `Share` page I can convert the string into a hash and then in the view check whether each attribute is present. If it is present I display the data, if not I don't.

Storing this data as a string seems wrong but I haven't been able to come up with a viable alternative. I could store each attribute on the `Share` model as a boolean but that would mean adding a new attribute to `Share` every time I add one to `Property`.

Any suggestions on how to tackle this?

Thanks.

Comment: Postgres has a json column type which I've used for similar problems. Allows you to store settings quite easily.